# How to Install Ubuntu with FreeDOS already Installed

Tags: system-installation

I just bought a new notebook with free DOS installed. I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I've been stuck in disk partitioning for 6 hours (even more). I've explored questions about it and I knew that it's normal to take a couple hours. But, I'm afraid that it's actually stuck. How do I know whether or not it's stuck? Is there a way to see the progress?

**P.S.** when I chose 'try ubuntu', I got an error message 'The system is running in low-graphics mode'. I pressed OK button, but it did nothing. Does it have something to do with my question above?

(**Edit:** the error has nothing to do with the problem as stated by Karel below.)

Comment: As Karel pointed our in the answer below your issue is likely not related to partitioning. Please [edit] your question with hardware specs (brand of notebook, graphics) so we can point you in the right direction. Also please remember to note and post any error messages you get - they are not meant to be forgotten but to help you solve your issues.

Comment: I guess I had 2 different issues here: (1) Installation with FreeDOS and (2) Low-graphics mode error. I've done the installation successfully but now the problem is the second one. I think I need to ask about it in another question, no?

Comment: You may find an answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do any disk partitioning before you install Ubuntu on a computer that comes with only FreeDOS preinstalled. The Ubuntu installer will take care of all the partitioning for you. If you choose the option in the *Installation type* window that says *Erase disk and install Ubuntu*, the Ubuntu installer will use the entire hard drive for Ubuntu and you won't need to do any manual partitioning.

The whole installation process from start to finish should take about a half hour. If the Ubuntu installer gets stuck for more than an hour in the middle of the installatiuon process, then you definitely have a problem installing Ubuntu. If you are installing Ubuntu on a computer that comes with only FreeDOS preinstalled, you can safely overwrite FreeDOS, as it no longer serves any purpose.

The error message that you got about graphics config has nothing to do with FreeDOS. If you have successfully installed Ubuntu, you should open the Additional Drivers utility and check if there are any proprietary graphics drivers available to be installed.

Comment: I end up doing it manually before I read your answer and I guess your answer hit the mark since I overwrote free DOS too and it worked. Thanks!